# How do I publish to Google Play if I'm under 18?

Tags: legal, publishing

I've finished my first Unity and want to release it on the Google Play store but can't because I am under 18.  The main issue is that Google Wallet [requires you to be over 18](https://wallet.google.com/legaldocument?family=0.buyertos&gl=GB).  How could I work around this?

Comment: I would think that these edge cases are taken described in the Terms of Service of the different services you want to use. Generally, you'll want a parent or tutor to do it for you.

Comment: ...also, you can't accept Google's Distribution Agreement in the first place, since you're legally a minor and are therefore not considered experienced enough to form binding contracts.

Comment: You cannot, legally speaking.

Answer (score 4):

From the Google Wallet ToS:

> By agreeing to the Agreement, You represent the following:
>
> 1. You are 13 to 17 years of age and creating a Google Wallet account for the sole and limited purpose of redeeming Google Play Gift Card value for select items that are eligible for purchase by You on Google Play, subject to applicable laws and upon Google's discretion; or
> 2. You are 18 years old or older and You are capable of entering into a legally-binding agreement.

I would suggest you ask a parent/tutor to create it for you. It might be a bit too much to ask them to manage all your stuff for you, but you could try and convince them to help you for the legal responsibility (c.f. *legally-binding agreement*), and you use the account the way you need to (and don't do stuff that would surprise them :P).

Comment: Note that if your parent/tutor accepts the contracts, it's not *your* stuff;  it's *their* stuff.  They may allow you to use their stuff, but don't get confused about who has the legal liability and the legal rights in that situation.